# LSTM Dimension are Incompatible

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, multiclass-classification

I am working with a multi classification problem using LSTM architecture. It seems to have an incompatible shapes error. Please help me to debug the model. Thanks in advance.

Here I have provided the model:

```
# build the network
model = Sequential()
model=models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(1024,activation='tanh',input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(512,activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

This the the summary of this LSTM model:

```
finished loading 7740 subjects from 3 classes
train / test split: 6192, 1548
training data shape:  (6192, 16000, 1)
training labels shape:  (6192, 3)
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 16000, 1024)       4202496   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 16000, 512)        3147776   
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 8192000)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 24576003  
=================================================================
Total params: 31,926,275
Trainable params: 31,926,275
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is the training/fitting:

```
results = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 500, batch_size=16,validation_data= (x_test, y_test))
```

Error I am getting:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 800, 20, 1)
```

Comment: Please avoid **bold**, except for emphasis (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a first sight, I presume that your problem comes from this line:

```
results = model.fit(x_train, x_train, epochs = 500, batch_size=16,validation_data= (x_test, x_test))
```

Normally we fit the train data to the labels. in the previous line, you are trying to fit the data to itself. But the model architecture you made is not for that.

So try to change it as follow:

```
results = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 500, batch_size=16,validation_data= (x_test, y_test)).
```

That was probably just a typo from your part. Change these lines and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I changed that. And I am getting dimension related errors. Here is that:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 800, 20, 1)

Comment: The input shape should normally be `(None,16000, 1)`. The error says that the input is `(None, 800, 20, 1)`. You probably need to reshape your input data. For example with `np.reshape(x, (16000,1))`.